# Column names and data types for Import Results file

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to see the error results that are stored in the Import folder after an attempted load. My client doesn't allow me to install FTP software on the company computer so I'm prevented from seeing the results the standard way.

It looks like you can use an Import to get the results file from the FTP folder and save the file to a Data Extension. What are the columns and data types for a Import Results file so I can create a Data Extension that can store the results?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311802/is-there-a-way-to-log-specific-rows-with-bad-data-from-an-import-activity-in-mar

This post might have what you need